# Raspberry Pi Pico - how to lower power consumption

Tags: power-management, pi-pico, micropython

I am using a Raspberry Pi Pico to provider a pacemaker signal to a broken flip clock that needs to trigger a change every 12 hours.

[image: Flip clock with Pi Pico]

As a proof of concept this works and does what it's designed to do. However the current 500mAh battery only lasts a single day. Please note the LCD LED is disabled during stand running, not on as shown in this image.

How can I lower the power consumption to increase the run time?

My current thoughts are:

- Remove/disable LEDs (Small indicator LEDs on some of the components used)
- Underclock the Pi (Touched on here https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=145&t=304309&p=1821617#p1821617, but the example links to create a new Pico image don't work)
- Use RTC to enter low power mode (However no MicroPython examples are available, so I'm unable to try this)

Comment: Have you checked if the pico supports the [machine](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.html) class and the `.deepsleep()` method?

Comment: They appear to be available, but don't allow for power saving currently according to https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=302163

Comment: Try the [SDK Documentation on RPi's GitHub repo](https://raspberrypi.github.io/pico-sdk-doxygen/group__sleep.html). This [Duck-Duck-Go search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=raspberry+pi+pico+sleep+mode&ia=web) might also be helpful.

Comment: If your python code isn't too complex you might consider converting it to C and then there is a [hello_sleep](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-playground/blob/master/sleep/hello_sleep/hello_sleep.c) example which should get current consumption down to 1.3mA.  Alternatively, though it seems a bit silly, you could add a $5 special-purpose [TPL5110 chip](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3435) to do the timing for you as an external switch with a supposed 20uA standby.

Comment: This doesn't look like a good project for a Raspberry Pi Pico due to its high current consumption. Shouldn't you be using another lower power microcontroller? (an arduino microcontroller with an external crystal should achieve less than ~10µA of consumption)

Comment: I did end up using an Aurduino @tglaria as documented at https://www.strifestreams.com/post/674616070385041408/back-in-the-summer-i-used-the-mighty-power-of-the

However I would rather revisit and use a Pi Pico for this project, if I was able

Comment: The Teensy 4 or 4.1 use an Arm core and has many ways to reduce power consumption to extreme levels.

Answer (score 1):

Recent git commits to MicroPython added optimized lightsleep to RP2040 with very low power consumption. You may want to revisit. Note that no existing builds include this feature hence you'd need to build firmware yourself (it's not complicated on any Linux box).